# Iam a lean guy I want to gain weight

Tags: weight-gain

Iam 16years old and my height is 5foot4inch and my wieght is 45kg so what can I do for my body

Comment: It really comes down to simply eating more food.

Answer (score 0):

Eat more food. More regular food and especially more protein if you want to add quality mass rather than just fat. Don't eat more sugar. Add protein shakes or even gainer shakes (protein + carbs) if that helps.

Also, remember that you have many years of growing left.